# Run function base on conditional statement

Tags: wordpress

In my WordPress functions file I have used the code

```
function banners() {

       if ( $GLOBALS['theme_settings']['banners'] == false ) {      
              wp_enqueue_style('banner', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/banners.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
            }
       }

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'banners');
```

and this works fine, however, I can't help but think there must be a better way because the add_action will sometimes be running with no file to enqueue. I have tried to put the conditional statement outside of the function but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're doing it is the correct way to do things. The `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook will fire whether or not you've even defined a function (to enqueue other admin scripts). The performance impact of what you're doing is negligible.